# Session variable disappears on specific machines

Tags: php, session

I'm using a PHP session variable to keep track of cart data before checkout.  I've tested multiple computers and every browser on each computer, and the session variable is maintained between the cart and checkout screen.  However, on the client's computers the data disappears some of the time, and a new session is started on the new page.  We've never been able to replicate the problem.

Between those two pages we move to a different directory and move from http: to https:, but in testing we've been able to keep session variables even while doing that on this site.  The client also has enabled third-party cookies.  I've looked at solutions for similar problems but they haven't helped.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is the session timing out?

Comment: The client reports that on their machine it immediately shows up as empty almost as soon as it's added, so I don't think it's timing out.

Comment: Could there be a browser restriction acting on the cookies?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on similar projects, but we were jumping domains (example.com -> secure.example.com) for checkout. The solution we used was to push the data into cache and add the cache key to the url. This way when the user landed on secure.example.com, we could get the cache key from the querystring, lookup the data in cache, and load necessary data. With this solution you never need to worry about session alignment.